# How to associate a date extracted from a pdf file with the data extracted from it using R?

Tags: r, pdf, dplyr, extract, text-mining

### What I Have

I have two .pdf files that have a table inside with buy and sell stock information and a date on top right corner header of each page. See the files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nhTDUWosZNufH94gg012ysIHi97et75n). If necessary save the two .pdf files and the script below into the same folder in your computer and run the script to reproduce the problem.

### What I Need

I want to extract just the table content from each file, join and transform it into a tibble and insert one first column (into a tibble) with dates extracted from header files.

So, if the first 5 lines in the tibble come from the first pdf file than the first 5 lines in the first column had to be filled in with the same date extract from the header of first file. If the next 2 lines after previous 5 ones come from the second file than these 2 lines in the first column had to be filled in with the same date extract from the header of the second file.

### What I've Already Tried

I've already extracted the table from each files, join and create a tibble as you can see below. Even create a code to extract the dates. But really, I don't know how to associate the date extracted from header to a table content of each file and insert it into the tibble.

**Code - Extract Table Information**

```
## EXTRACT PDF FILE INFORMATION AND GENERATE A CLEAN DATASET

# load library
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)


# create a list with all file names
file_names <- dir(pattern = 'N.*')


# extract text from each file and append into a list
text_raw <- list()
for (i in 1:length(file_names)) {
        doc <- pdf_text(file_names[i])
        text_raw <- append(text_raw, doc)
}


# clean data
text_clean <- text_raw %>% 
        str_split('\r\n') %>%
        unlist() %>% 
        as.vector() %>% 
        str_to_lower() %>% 
        str_squish() %>% 
        str_subset('1-bovespa') %>% 
        str_replace('1-', '') %>% 
        str_remove_all('#2?|on|nm|sa') %>% 
        str_squish()


# convert as tibble
df <- tbl_df(text_clean)

# split column
df <- separate(df, 
                value, 
                c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8'),
                sep = ' ')
print(df)
```

**Code - Extract Dates**

```
# filter dates
dates <- text_raw %>% 
        str_split('\r\n') %>% 
        unlist() %>% 
        as.vector() %>% 
        str_squish() %>% 
        str_subset('\\d{4}\\s\\d{1}\\s\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}$') %>% 
        str_remove_all('(\\d+\\s\\d{1}\\s)')

print(dates)
```

### Actual Output

```
   c1       c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7        c8   
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 bovespa  c     vista cielo 800   10,79 8.632,00  d    
2 bovespa  c     vista cielo 200   10,79 2.158,00  d    
3 bovespa  c     vista brf   400   23,81 9.524,00  d    
4 bovespa  c     vista brf   100   23,81 2.381,00  d
```

### Expected Output

```
   c1           c2       c3    c4    c5    c6    c7     c8        c9
  <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>
1 10/01/2019   bovespa  c     vista cielo 800   10,79  8.632,00  d    
2 10/01/2019   bovespa  c     vista cielo 200   10,79  2.158,00  d    
3 18/01/2019   bovespa  c     vista brf   400   23,81  9.524,00  d    
4 18/01/2019   bovespa  c     vista brf   100   23,81  2.381,00  d
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the effort to extract dates was unnecessarily complex, not to mention the fact that it appears to have worked for some of us but failed for my running of the code. Instead I constructed a date-pattern and extracted with `stringi::stri_extract`:

```
 stringi::stri_extract( regex="[0-3][0-9]/[01][0-9]/20[0-1][0-9]", text_clean)
[1] "18/01/2019"  # this pattern designed for this century dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format

 dates <- stringi::stri_extract( regex="[0-3][0-9]/[01][0-9]/20[0-1][0-9]", text_clean)

 df$C9 <- dates
```

Furthermore, since there were multiple matches for the date pattern in each pdf, it would be safer to do the extraction before appending the text together and then you could use only the first values.

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion. I will check the extraction before appending.

Comment: I believe that extraction date code doesn't work because **pdftools** and **tidyverse** libraries need to be loaded. Your code works well but extract more dates than what we need because the file to extract is **text_raw** and not **text_clean**. The last one doesn't has any date. Thanks @42-.

Answer (score -1):

```
df$c0=dates
print(df)
```

hi,I am a chinese.

[image]

**you should just rename the colname :**

```
colnames(df)=c("c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9")
df$c1=dates
print(df)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since dates has a value of `character(0)` (not to mention the several other problems with this answer.)

Comment: just rename the colname is:

colnames(df)=c("c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9")
df$c1=dates
print(df)

Comment: Thanks for your help, @lyq. Don't worry about the column class as `character(0)`. In that case doesn't matter. I insert the code line `df$c0=dates` as you suggest but the dates are fill in the lines randomly. So some dates extracted from the second file was associated to lines that came from the first file and that's not acceptable to solve this problem. Imagine 1,000 files to be extracted. How to insert the dates from a file exactly in the same lines extracted from the same file? I'm looking for a reproducible code. Thanks anyway!!!